# Почему во внешнем классе нельзя создать объект внутреннего класса?

Tags: c++

Почему во внешнем классе нельзя создать объект внутреннего класса?

```
class d {
public:
    int data = 90;
    static const int n = 9;

    class t {
        friend class d;
        int yy = 0;
    public:
        int y;
        t(int b) :y(b) {};
        const int v = d::n;//тк статик не через объект
    };
    t nn(3);//ошибка?
```

Comment: Параметры в конструктор членов класса нужно передавать в конструкторе этого класса: `t nn; d() : nn(5) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в круглых скобках. Внутри класса компилятор всегда принимает их за список параметров функции. Используйте одно из:

- `t nn = 3;`
- `t nn{3};`
- `t nn = t(3);`
- ...